# SQL Server incorrect syntax exception when executing with sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, syntax-error

I am calling a procedure from a trigger and passing some parameters from trigger to procedure. Parameters are:

```
@table_name varchar(128), @where_str varchar(200)
```

Inside the procedure, I'm executing a command with `sp_executesql`. I think, I am using incorrect syntax, but I couldn't find the resolution.

This is the executed query:

```
  SET @SqlString = N'update @ptable_name set RepSt=2 @pwhere_str';  
  SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ptable_name varchar(128), @pwhere_str varchar(200)';  

  execute sp_executesql @SqlString, @ParmDefinition, 
                        @ptable_name = @table_name, @pwhere_str = @where_str;
```

Passed parameters are like that:

- `@table_name` is `[MyTable]`
- `@where_str = N'where MyColumnA = '+@oldMyColumnA+N' AND MyColumnB = '+@oldMyColumnB+N' AND MyColumnC = '+@oldMyColumnC;`

Comment: And somehow, magically, we will know what values were sent to those parameters?  The syntax cannot be checked without the parameter values.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I updated the question as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you end up executing is something like:

```
DECLARE @ptable_name VARCHAR(128) = 'your_Table'
,       @pwhere_str VARCHAR(200) = 'Your_where_clause'

UPDATE  @ptable_name
SET     RepSt=2
WHERE   @pwhere_str
```

This doesn't work, you need to replace the variable *in* the executed sql:

```
SET @SqlString = N'update @ptable_name set RepSt=2 @pwhere_str';  
SET @SqlString = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SqlString, '@ptable_name', @table_name), '@pwhere_str', @where_str)

execute sp_executesql @SqlString
```

(Very dirty, but this is the idea.)

Comment: I am using this solution and I want to thank you. For using int variables in a concatanated sql string, replacing is a lifesaving solution.

Answer (score 0):

SET @SqlString =N'update ' + @ptable_name + ' set RepSt=2 @pwhere_str';

Comment: It won't work. It works when you declared @ptable_name before this set clause.